# How to POST with a field which is not specified in Form's Meta fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I wanted to just add `referenceData` to the `class Meta` fields and use it, but the number of options for `<select>` was too high, so instead of doing this I added a `reference` field to the `ModelForm` and then read the data record referenced by this value. However, when POST is done, only `referenceData` field is missing and data is created.

#### views.py

```
    class CorrectView(IndexView):
        ...
        form_class = DataCorrectForm
        ...
        def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            form = self.form_class(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():            
                the_form = form.save(commit=False) 
                the_form.clean() # HERE !
                the_form.save()  # HERE !
                return self.form_valid(form)
            else:
                return self.form_invalid(form)
```

#### forms.py

```
    class DataCorrectForm(forms.ModelForm):
        reference = forms.IntegerField()
        def clean(self):
            cleaned_data = super(DataCorrectForm, self).clean()
            cleaned_data['referenceData'] = DataNeedsCorrection.objects.get(data_id=cleaned_data['reference']) 
            # I extract a record that matches data_id and assign it to the form data
            return cleaned_data


        def save(self, commit=True):
            return super(DataCorrectForm, self).save(commit=commit)


        class Meta:
            model = DataCorrected
            fields = [
                'reference',
                 # 'referenceData', # If I comment this out it works! but not that I wanted 
                'correctedText',
            ]
```

If I comment out the `'referenceData'`, at least POST works and data record is properly created but it is a method that can not be adopted.

#### models.py

```
    class DataCorrected(models.Model):
        data_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        referenceData = models.ForeignKey('DataNeedsCorrection', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        correctedText = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        ...

    class DataNeedsCorrection(models.Model):
        data_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey('WatCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        originalText = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        translatedText = models.CharField(max_length=300)
        ...
```

The current DataCorrected model is `null = True`, but please note that this is what I did to test it.

I would really appreciate it if you could point out any other improvements. Thanks for reading.

---

I updated `self.fields['referenceData']` to `None` field so I can hide many fields. Below, I posted a snapshot of the page.

[image]

As you can see, if a user clicks a row in the data list, javascript updates the values of referenceData, reference, and correctedText fields. And the user finalizes the correctedText and submits it.

And here are the problems.

1. If I use `referenceData` fields as is in the django form fields, it shows too many fields in the frontend side (about 100,000 rows which is unselectable ).
2. So I tried `self.fields['referenceData'] = DataNeedsCorrection.objects.none().`
   This can hide fields effectively but it doesn't respond to `document.getElementById('id_referenceData').value = some_id` since it has no option values. So I cannot submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason. An alternative would be to include the field you want in the form's Meta class and alter the queryset in the form's `__init__` method.

```
class DataCorrectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    reference = forms.IntegerField()
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(DataCorrectForm, self).clean()
        cleaned_data['referenceData'] = DataNeedsCorrection.objects.get(data_id=cleaned_data['reference']) 
        # I extract a record that matches data_id and assign it to the form data
        return cleaned_data


    def save(self, commit=True):
        return super(DataCorrectForm, self).save(commit=commit)


    class Meta:
        model = DataCorrected
        fields = [
            'reference',
            'referenceData',
            'correctedText',
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DataCorrectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.field['referenceData'].queryset = DataNeedsCorrection.objects.none()
```

If this doesn't match what you're looking for let me know(so I can delete it or provide another solution).

Additional changes I would suggest:

- You're overriding the `save` method in the form but not doing anything new. I'd remove that.
- Remove `the_form.clean()`. This happens in `form.is_valid()`
- I'm not sure what the `IndexView` is, but if it inherits from the `FormView`, your whole entire `post` method is unnecessary.
- Django already provides a primary key, so you don't need to add the AutoFields

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. 

you suggested initializing `referenceData` at first, however, I get `reference` id from html form field from which I can decide specific `referenceData`. That means I don't know the `reference` at the beginning.

Comment: That's fine. You can set the queryset to `DataNeedsCorrection.objects.none()`. I updated my original answer to reflect this.

Comment: I also added some general suggestions for the code you provided.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code and while doing it I got the point what you intended (by initializing the field to none to hide too many options.) By the way, I feel I have to describe my problem more specifically so I added some more contents to the post.